# SSL_accept() fails with return value -1

Tags: sockets, tcp, openssl

In order to understand `SSL/TLS`, I downloaded `OpenSSL-1.0.2k` on `Windows-7` and compiled with `Cygwin` `gcc` `64 bit` compiler. I took `off-the-shelf` example of server/client from [OpenSSL server/client example in c](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.de/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html#!/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html) and compiled with `cygwin gcc`. Compilation is successful on the first go. I executed server and client from `cmd` with following commands.

```
(Server)   D:\>ssl-server.exe 5000
(Client)   D:\>ssl-client.exe 127.0.0.1 5000
```

Client exits without any response but on the other hand, server displays that it has made a connection, e.g;

```
Connection: 127.0.0.1:50475
```

and waits on next line infinitely.

Then I started debugging server side and found that , `SSL_accept()` in procedure `void Servlet(SSL* ssl)` returns a value of `-1`, which is not expected. I consulted Documentation from `OpenSSL` [openSSL DOC](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_accept.html);

> The TLS/SSL handshake was not successful because a fatal error occurred either at the protocol level or a connection failure occurred. The shutdown was not clean. It can also occur of action is need to continue the operation for non-blocking BIOs. Call SSL_get_error() with the return value ret to find out the reason.

`SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. I checked the value of `errno` right after this call and I see `no error`. Complete code of `Servlet` method follows. Rest of the code is same as in link.

```
void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{   char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";
    int ret;
    ret = SSL_accept(ssl);  /* do SSL-protocol accept */ 
    if ( ret == -1 )    
    {
        // printf(" SSL_accept() returned -1\n");
        switch(SSL_get_error(ssl, ret) )
        {
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                perror("errno");
                break;
            default:
                printf( "default" );
                break;
        }
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if ( ret == 0)
    {
        printf(" SSL_accept() returned 0\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if ( ret == 1) // The TLS/SSL connection has been established. 
    {
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
        if ( bytes > 0 )
        {
            buf[bytes] = 0;
            printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
            sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
}
```

Comment: So what was the value of `SSL_get_error()`?

Comment: `switch-case` is entering into default case.  `printf("default\n");
` executes from my code. `printf("ret: %i\n", ret);` line before `switch` statement outputs `-1`

Comment: @EJP `SSL_get_error()` returns `5` which is basically `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL `

Comment: So you got SSL_ERROR_SYCALL, now you have to find the value of `errno`, or call `perror()`. This is all documented. All this information should have already been included in the question.

Comment: Initially I was not checking the integer value, now I checked when you asked this question. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @EJP I checked `ret = SSL_accept(ssl); 
    printf("ErroR: %s\n", strerror(ret));` but it prints `Unknown Error -1`

Comment: Sigh. `strerror(l)` is meaningless here, as is `strerror(ret)` when `ret` is -1. Think about it. You need `strerror(errno)`, or `perror()`. So far all this is trivially obvious and should have been done right and its result posted in the question  in the first place.

Comment: If you are using non-blocking sockets, then this may help: [SSL_accept -1 non-blocking](https://www.google.com/search?q=SSL_accept+"-1"+non-blocking).

Comment: @jww I have blocking sockets.

Comment: Error 5 looks like input/output blocking error. Could it be that I am running server on localhost? Firewall something?

Comment: @GulluButt Error 5 is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. You said so yourself. You are getting hopelessly confused between `ret`, which is -1, `l`, which is the result of `SSL_get_error()`, which is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, and `errno`, which you haven't yet made the slightest attempt to ascertain or show here, which is the only thing of actual interest. **What is the result of `strerror(errno)`?** Until you provide that information, your question is unanswerable, and all you will get is more well-meaning guesswork such as already appears above.

Comment: @EJP I have edited my question with recent updates. Please check.

Comment: You have edited your question with everything you can think of *except* what I have now asked for three or four times, starting over an hour ago. It is time for you to stop guessing, and futzing around, and start paying some attention to what you're being told here, and what you're being asked to provide.

Comment: @EJP Actually I did not get you. what do you mean by `errno` ? What I understood is so. `errno = SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` which is `5` in turn. If I check `strerror(errno)` the result is `Input/Output Error ` and that I have already in my 2nd edit. or you are asking something else?

Comment: That is all nonsense. You have not checked `strerror(errno)`. According to your own post, 'Input/Output Error' resulted from `strerror(l)`, which as I have already stated is meaningless. This is really quite incredible. What part of 'what is the result of `strerror(errno)`?' don't you understand? I am not 'asking something else', but you are making an art form out of *answering* something else, to a perfectly simple question. Stop wasting time.

Comment: No, I don't understand you. what value is in `errno` ? where does this `errno` comes from? it is 5. `l`is also 5. what makes difference here.

Comment: `errno` is a system variable provided by the C library which provides the error code from the last system call that failed. This is extremely basic Unix knowledge. You cannot hope to do Unix systems programming without it. If you're on Windows you should use `WSAGetLastError()`. But I am unable to comprehend your difficulty here. I've given you the code. You haven't even bothered to just cut and paste it.

Comment: I ran your code initially when you said first time. It return `no error`. I have checked many times. I am on windows using Cygwin gcc.

Comment: Really. You've wasted well over an hour not telling us that, and not telling us that you are running on Windows. Please post the actual code you used and the actual output from it. In your question. Clearly you didn't do it correctly, because there *was* an error, because SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL said so. You need to call `perror()` and friends immediately you get the original error, not after any other system calls.

Comment: After `SSL_accept(ssl);` directly I called `perror("Error:");` and the result is `no error`

Comment: So there wasn't an error that time. As I just said, 'you need to call [it] immediately you get the original error'. It only means something *if there was an error*. Calling it unconditionally is futile. Again this is all extremely basic knowledge that you should already have. It is debatable whether you are well enough equipped for your task.

Comment: I am running an off the shelf example code from internet, I am new. I thought this group is for learning and solving problems.

Comment: You are running code you have fiddled with endlessly and pointlessly so it is probably unrecognizable compared to the original. You need to add a case for SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and call `perror("SSL_accept")` inside it. I consider this also to be trivially obvious. I note that after two hours we are still no nearer solving the actual problem than we were two hours ago.

Comment: still `no error` in edit-4.

Comment: Sigh. This is incredible. **Can you possibly read what I wrote.** 'You need  to call [it] immediately ... not after any other system calls'. `printf()` calls `write()`, which is another system call. Get rid of the `printf()`s. NB There is none of this junk error-handling in the source you claim to be copying.

Comment: After `ret = SSL_accept(ssl)` function call, it registers the error to `error-queue` if any and then I call `SSL_get_error(ssl, ret) inside the switch. there is no other system call now. Result is same `no error`

Comment: I don't know what 'registers the error to `error-queue`' means, or where it is implemented in your code, or what system calls it may use if any, and I also don't know why you aren't using the one-liner error handling in your claimed source, instead of wasting your life reinventing the wheel, but in any case, according to your current code, there is no evidence for your first sentence 'on server side (openSSL), `SSL_accept()` fails with return value -1'. You are calling `SSL_get_error()` *regardless* of what `SSL_accept()` returned. The question now is, is there a problem at all?

Answer (score 4):

1. When you don't hit one of the SSL_ERROR_ cases you have enumerated, you should trace the value of `SSL_get_error()` so you can start debugging. Rather than just throwing up your hands.
2. In this case the value was `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. You didn't catch it where you thought you should because `case (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || SSL_ERROR_SSL || SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT || SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT):` doesn't do what you think. It will turn into `case 1` because of the semantics of `||`. There should be separate `case` statements for each value.
3. `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` means that the underlying error is in `errno`, as per the documentation you quoted yourself, which means that you should then trace *that*. Rather than just throwing up your hands. And note that you must do so *before calling any other system calls* (such as `write()` via `printf()`), so it might help to save `errno` immediately.
4. You can either print `errno` directly with `printf("errno=%d\n", errno)`, but it would be more useful to print the error *message*, which you can do with either `perror()` or `printf("error=%s\n", strerror(errno))`.
5. The value of `SSL_get_error()` is not an `errno` value, and neither is the original -1 you started with. An `errno` value comes from the `errno` variable.
6. However you shouldn't do *any* of these things *unless* `SSL_accept()` returned -1, *for which there is no actual evidence here.*

So it is entirely possible that there is no error here at all.

Comment: `SSL_accept()` returns `-1`, I made it sure. I have also re structured my question with more detail and deleted extra things.

Comment: So what was printed by `perror()`? Which was the **original question, YESTERDAY?**

Comment: On item number 4, the function should be `strerror(errno)`