# Error with non-blocking handshake SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl

I wrote a little SSL enabled embedded webserver to run on linux. It works quite well. Beside of one thing.

On `SSL_accept()` it returns -1 (for OpenSSL 1.1.0) or 0 (for OpenSSL 1.0.2) and `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

In my isolated testenvironment I have no problem even when I send in 3 million requests. But when running on AWS (same CentOS 7) or on another VM which is connected to the internet I see quite frequently these problems. The application also hangs for some seconds when this happens.

This is the relevant code part of my listening thread:

```
int myPort = 443;
struct sockaddr_in serverSockAddr;
memset(&serverSockAddr,0,sizeof(serverSockAddr));

serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons(myPort);
serverSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int tcpListenSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (tcpListenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    int val = 1;
    setsockopt(tcpListenSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&val,sizeof(val));
    if (bind(tcpListenSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&serverSockAddr,sizeof(serverSockAddr)) == 0)
    {
        if (listen(tcpListenSocket,128) != 0) // Allow 128 backlog connections
        {
            printf("Failed to listen on port: %d\n",myPort);
            tcpListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not able to bind port: %d (%d-%s)\n",myPort,errno,strerror(errno));
        tcpListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
}

if (tcpListenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("TCP Listen Thread: Socket for port %d bound\n",myPort);
    printf("TCP Listen Thread: Waiting for incoming data\n");

    // Hostname or IP Adress of client who sent the request. Allocate here to avoid reallocation on stack on each accept.
    char clientHostName[NI_MAXHOST];
    clientHostName[0] = '\0';

    while (_tcpListenShutdown == 0)
    {
        // wait for incoming data
        int pendingConnection = 0;
        do
        {
            struct timeval tv;
            fd_set descriptor;

            tv.tv_sec = 0;
            tv.tv_usec = 75000; // 75ms
            FD_ZERO(&descriptor);
            FD_SET(tcpListenSocket,&descriptor);

            pendingConnection = select(tcpListenSocket+1,&descriptor,NULL,NULL,&tv);                        
        }while((_tcpListenShutdown == 0) && (pendingConnection == 0));

        if (pendingConnection > 0)
        {
            struct sockaddr_in clientSockAddr;
            ovsocklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientSockAddr);
            memset(&clientSockAddr,0,sizeof(clientSockAddr));

            int clientSocket = accept(tcpListenSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientSockAddr,&clientAddrLen);
            if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                // find hostname who originates connection
                getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&clientSockAddr,sizeof(clientSockAddr),clientHostName,sizeof(clientHostName),NULL,0,0);

                // If resolving failed use IP address
                if (clientHostName[0] == '\0')
                    strlcpy(clientHostName,inet_ntoa(clientSockAddr.sin_addr),sizeof(clientHostName));

                int clientPort = ntohs(clientSockAddr.sin_port);
                printf("TCP Listen Thread: Received connection from host '%s:%d' on clientsocket:'%d'\n",clientHostName,clientPort,clientSocket);

                SSL *sslSession = NULL;
                // create SSL Session
                int error = 1;
                sslSession = SSL_new(_sslContext);
                if (sslSession)
                {
                    // hook to our own client socket
                    SSL_set_fd(sslSession,clientSocket);

                    printf("TCP Listen Thread('%s:%d'): Accepting on SSL session\n",clientHostName,clientPort);
                    // SSL_Accept() might need to be repeated if socket is non blocking
                    while (error)
                    {
                        int acceptResult = SSL_accept(sslSession);
                        if (acceptResult == 1)
                            error = 0;
                        else
                        {
                            int sslError = SSL_get_error(sslSession,acceptResult);
                            if ((sslError == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) || (sslError == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE))
                                continue;
                            else
                            {
                                printf("TCP Listen Thread('%s:%d'): Could not accept SSL session(%d/%d) (%d-%s)",clientHostName,clientPort,acceptResult,sslError,errno,strerror(errno));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    printf("TCP Listen Thread('%s:%d'): Could not generate SSL session\n",clientHostName,clientPort);

                // create new thread for handling new connection
                if (error == 0)
                {
                    /// SSL Handshake complete => Handle request
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("TCP Listen Thread('%s:%d'): Dropping connection due to errors.\n",clientHostName,clientPort);
                    if (sslSession)
                        SSL_free(sslSession);
                    shutdown(clientSocket,SHUT_RDWR);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_tcpListenShutdown == 0)
                printf("TCP Listen Thread: Lost connection => exiting\n");
        }
    }
```

An example error message:

> TCP Listen
>   Thread('ec2-54-248-220-38.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:43507'):
>   Could not accept SSL session(-1/5) (0-Success)

The -1 is the result of `SSL_accept()`
5 is the result of `SSL_get_error()` which means `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`
And the rest is the errno and its string representation.

The error messages appear usually in a block of 3 to 15 messages of the same kind but from different hosts. It looks like the thread would block for some time and when it continues the appearing messages represent connection attempts which could not have been fulfilled in a timely manner.

Any idea to isolate and fix this problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `errno` is `0` and `strerror(errno)` is `Success` ?? I have also the similar results except I get result of `no error` from `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259683/ssl-accept-fails-with-return-value-1

Comment: The code posted won't even call `SSL_accept()`.  After `int error = 0;` there is no assignment to `error` to set it to anything other than `0`, yet the `SSL_accept()` call is in a `while()` loop:  `while (error)...`  That loop will never be entered in the posted code.

Comment: What is output of `ERR_error_string()` ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually my code is spread amongs subfunctions. I have copied together here and so made a bug with the initial value of `error`. `error` is initialized to 1, so the `while()` loop is indeed entered. Corrected my example.

Comment: @GulluButt: The error returned by `ERR_error_string(SSL_get_error(sslSession,acceptResult),someBuffer)` is: `error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib`

Comment: I have similar error. this `DH` is `Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange` probably what I understood until now. you may look this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479376/openssl-ssl-accept-error-5   
If you could solve this problem, I am trying to understand this `DH` thing.

Comment: @GulluButt: I do have setup DH params. With self calculated params. I have also tried some sample params from [OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie-Hellman_parameters). But this does not change anything.

Comment: @Rosch *Actually my code is spread amongs subfunctions. I have copied together here...* So [post a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Something that someone can compile and use to reproduce your error.